# Windows Server 2012 Performance Counter Data Error

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I am trying to get a W2012 R2 AD server up and running on my company's local network. I configured it as a local server for file sharing and domain controller where users could log on to their accounts using their login details created in the server.

While logging into the system (from a different PC in the network), I was not able to login. I was getting an error that the ADDS name does not exist. The ADDS name is dc.companyname.com. The computer/server name is COMPANYNAME-DC.

I then checked in the command prompt to see that the DNS server entries were 127.0.0.1. I then proceeded to change the DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4. Now when I go to the server manager, all the roles and features are red (which didn't happen before) and in the detail view under manageability, it shows me 'Online - Cannot get performance counter data. The start time must be earlier than the end time'.

My questions are how do I get the performance counter issue resolved and how do I allow users registered in the domain to log in successfully?